# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mern

everything is working fine but when i run this code it start loading and it shows timeout error it
doesn't send data to database

```
const User = require("../models/User");

//REGISTER
router.get("/register", async ( req, res) => {
    const user = await new User({
        username:"hamza",
        email:"hamza@gmail.com",
        password:"12345"
    });
        await user.save();
        res.send("ok");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Do you operate elsewhere with the `User` model? There may be a problem with the `User` model. There is no problem with the code you showed.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, I would recommend checking the connection string/URI to your MongoDB instance for typo's, (in particular the credential details) as you will receive variations of this error upon attempting to execute most any database operation, with little context pointing to the underlying problem.